# Why is my string not being printed?

Tags: c++, string, std, cout

I have some code that, in its smallest complete form that exhibits the problem (being a good citizen when it comes to asking questions), basically boils down to the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    int x = 11;
    std::string s = "Value was: " + x;
    std::cout << "[" << s << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm expecting it to output

```
[Value was: 11]
```

Instead, instead of that, I'm getting just:

```
[]
```

Why is that? Why can I not output my string? Is the string blank? Is `cout` somehow broken? Have I gone *mad?*

Comment: You need to include `<string>` for this to "work" in a compliant manner, by the way.

Comment: Good point, how is this even compiling?

Comment: `gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3` compiles that without errors - maybe it's just forgiving. In any case, adding string doesn't help so I'll add it to the question so we're more kosher. However, Xeo beat me to it so thanks :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"Value was: "` is of type `const char[12]`. When you add an integer to it, you are effectively referencing an element of that array. To see the effect, change `x` to `3`.

You will have to construct an `std::string` explicitly. Then again, you cannot concatenate an `std::string` and an integer. To get around this you can write into an `std::ostringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Value was: " << x;
std::string result = oss.str();
```

Comment: In this case, since the number is `11` and the length of the string is 11, the resulting pointer points right at the null terminator.

Comment: It's of the type `const char[12]`, actually.

Comment: `char[11]` actually (I think).

Comment: @paxdiablo: `const char[12]`. It's zero-terminated implicitly.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, you're actually right about the 12, I miscounted. However, you're not quite so right about the `const`. While it's undefined to try and change them, string literals are `char`, not `const char`. Except the wide ones which aren't `char`, but I'm still pretty sure those aren't `const` either, even though I've never used them. Not that it affects my upvote for this answer :-)

Comment: or alternatively the statement can be modified as std::string s = string("Value was: ") + x;

Comment: It used to be `char[]`, but according to http://www.glenmccl.com/ansi_014.htm it was decided to change it to `const char[]`. I don't know if this change already applies or if it's for the upcoming C++ standard.

Comment: @hype: No, it cannot. This gives a _no match for ‘operator+’ in std::basic_string_ error.

Comment: @pax: §2.13.4/1, C++03: "An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char” and static storage duration (3.7), where n is the size of the string"

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a character pointer and an integer like that (you can, but it won't do what you expect).

You'll need to convert the x to a string first. You can either do it out-of-band the C way by using the itoa function to convert the integer to a string:

```
char buf[5];
itoa(x, buf, 10);

s += buf;
```

Or the STD way with an sstream:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << s << x;
std::cout << oss.str();
```

Or directly in the cout line:

```
std::cout << text << x;
```

Comment: Wouldn't he still run into problems because x is of type int, not string or char*?

Comment: That gives me `[Value was <CTRL-K>]` (had to pipe through `od -xcb` to see what was going on there.

Comment: When you do `S += x;` it is converting integer 11 to char 11 and tries to get the corresponding ASCII character.

Answer (score 4):

Amusing :) That's what we pay for C-compatibility and the lack of a built-in `string`.

Anyway, I think the most readable way to do it would be:

```
std::string s = "Value was: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x);
```

Because the `lexical_cast` return type is `std::string` here, the right overload of `+` will be selected.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't concatenate strings using the the + operator. There's also no auto-promote from data types to string.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, you cannot append an integer to a character array using the `+` operator because a `char` array decays to a pointer. To append an `int` to a `string`, use `ostringstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (void) {  
  int x = 11;
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << "Value was: " << x;
  std::string s = out.str();
  std::cout << "[" << s << "]" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```